# Javascript filter strings by matching input?

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the most efficient way to filter a list of strings character by character?

```
var term = "Mike";
angular.forEach($scope.contacts, function(contact, key) {

    // if I had the whole term and 
    // contact.name == Mike then this is true
    contact.name == term;

});
```

The above would be fine, but if I am building a search how can I filter character by character?

```
var term = "Mi";
angular.forEach($scope.contacts, function(contact, key) {

    // contact.name == Mike, but term == Mi how can I get this to return true?
    contact.name == term;

});
```

Comment: You really have to define what a partial match would mean, so for your last example there, would "Tommie" be a valid match?  Depending on the rules you come up with there are lots of different ways to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `indexOf`

```
var term = "Mi";
angular.forEach($scope.contacts, function(contact, key) {

    // contact.name == Mike, but term == Mi how can I get this to return true?
    contact.name.indexOf(term) > -1;

});
```

If you want case insensitive testing, you can do

```
    var term = "Mi";
    var regex = new RegExp(term, 'i');

    angular.forEach($scope.contacts, function(contact, key) {

        // contact.name == Mike, but term == Mi how can I get this to return true?
        regex.test(contact.name);

    });
```

Comment: Your case-insensitive solution uses a regular expression, this can change the meaning of `term` for characters with special meaning in the regular expression language. Instead consider converting both values to the same case (ie. `toLowerCase()`) and do an `indexOf`.

Comment: Great advice Halcyon, definitely will do that now :)

Comment: @Halcyon, I am not sure what you mean by `this can change the meaning of term`. Do you mean linguistically, or will there be unintended side effects programmatically?

Comment: If `term` is `Mi*` you will match `mi`, `miii` but also `m`.

Comment: @Halcyon, sorry, still not understanding :-). Doing this in the console `new RegExp('Mi', 'i').test('m')` gives me `false`